# How did they program the very first IDE?

Tags: c

If C was used to program Unix, what was used to program in C? and so on and so on, ie. how did they create the very first program?

Comment: [A magnetized needle and a steady hand](http://xkcd.com/378/).

Comment: Probably you should ask this in **http://programmers.stackexchange.com/**

Comment: The first program was created when there were no computers at all. By Ada Lovelace.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_programming_languages

Comment: The first computer programs were not "written", they were "hardwired" ([ENIAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ENIAC), [Z3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z3_%28computer%29) and others). The next step was storing the program in memory; then someone wrote a program that would translate a "programming language" (Assembly) into a program in memory. And from there on, programming languages evolved. At first, all languages are written in *another* language, but sooner or later many of them (the better ones...) become "self-hosted", i.e. the compiler / interpreter is written in the language itself.

Answer (score 6):

Very first c compiler was written in assembly language. Assembly language is written in binary language. And binary language is hardware language, it is directly executed by hardware.

I quote [David Rabinowitz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1653658/517491):

> Please read about [compiler bootstrapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_%28compilers%29) and the [history of
>   compiler writing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_compiler_writing)
>
> The idea is to write a very simple compiler directly in machine code,
>   use it to write a more sophisticated compiler, use the second one to
>   build a third one and so on until you can have a full featured
>   compiler.

See the complete thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653649/how-was-the-first-compiler-written).

Comment: what did they use to write assembly language?

Comment: Why dont give some more information about a interesting subject?

Comment: @Tim I have made edit, please have a look.

Comment: @Backwards_Dave I have made an edit please have a look

Comment: @djaqeel Very nice and useful information, thanks!