# Is compiler common to all programming languages

Tags: compiler-construction, interpreter

For different programming languages, is there different compiler or the compiler will be common to all the programming languages? In which language compiler will be written.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is daft.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_%28compilers%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A compiler is a special program that processes statements written in a particular programming language and turns them into machine language or "code" that a computer's processor uses. Typically, a programmer writes language statements in a language such as Pascal or C one line at a time using an editor . The file that is created contains what are called the source statements . The programmer then runs the appropriate language compiler, specifying the name of the file that contains the source statements.

So clearly, every language has its own specific language supported compiler to convert source code into machine code.

refer to this link for more information related to language in which compiler is written : [How was the first compiler written?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653649/how-was-the-first-compiler-written)

I agree with above answer that java or other high level programming language's compiler must be written in C etc because it is a language closely related to machine.

Comment: Instead of saying "above" it would be better to refer to another answer by the user's name. For example `drj`. This is because the answers are not sorted chronologically and the accepted answer is generally sorted at the top. Currently there are zero answers above this answer so something doesn't make sense.

Comment: No, compilers of high-level programming languages don't have to be written in C or any other *"language closely related to machine"*. A compiler for any language can be written in any language. For example C# compiler (Roslyn) is written in C# and you could build a compiler for any language in C#.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the thing:

- Machines are dumb, they understand the language of binary digits ie. 1's and 0's
- earlier **there existed no *translators*** so programmers were forced to give instructions in the language of the machine, which was difficult as it involved rewiring switches.
- Then, in 1951, Grace Hopper developed the first **compiler, which allowed the computer to be programmed using words and symbols** rather than binary ones and zeroes. by "programming" we mean giving instructions. This made writing programs easier and the written instruction were refereed to as **"Source Codes"**
- the primary **job of any compiler is to perform the act of "compilation" ie. take this source code from the user  (once written completely) and turn it into the "machine language" according to certain rules.** Thus acting as translators.
- now since **different programming languages have different set of rules there exists different compilers specific to each such programming language** These "rules" are basically syntactical and lexical rules, ie. what words and symbols can be used and how they can be combined to make some piece of code.
- A compiler is heavily dependent on Automata theory to perform it's job of compilation.

---

- As the techniques of programming developed other ways of converting
  source code to machine language came into existence, this gave rise
  to **interpreted languages which involves compillation of
  each sentence or subroutein directly into machine language
  instructions.** such compilation is performed by an **interpreter**.example: JavaScript
- **Today compilers and interpreters are used together to get best
  performance and increase usability on machines.** example: Java which
  is a compiled as well as interpreted language.

**I believe the term "Compiler" is very generic.

Comment: You should replace dumb with something like unintelligent. Some computers actually _can_ speak :-)

Comment: I am willing to take my chances. :-P

Answer (score 2):

You may be confusing a compiler (e.g. GCC) with an IDE (e.g. Microsoft Visual Studio.) The compiler is language-specific; the IDE can support multiple languages, each of which has a specific compiler.

Comment: That's not entirely true. Different languages can use the same compiler-backend while having different compiler front ends. GCC is an example.

Answer (score 0):

Different languages have different compilers.Compiler is written in some other language not every time, for java the compiler is written in C.

Answer (score 0):

Compilation is a multistep process which usually includes the following steps;

1. Lexical analysis
2. Parsing
3. Code generation
4. Optimisation

Lexical analyzer converts the high level input program into a sequence of tokens. Parser will generate a parse tree. In code generation, the target code (machine code) will be generated. Optimisation is intended to improve the performance and can happen at any level.

Stages upto code generation can be referred to as compiler front-end. Remaining stages comprise compiler backend. Multiple languages can have different front ends to generate the parse tree after which they can use the same compiler backend to generate machine code.

GCC adopts this model. For more information you may refer [gcc.gnu.org](https://%20https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/G_002b_002b-and-GCC.html#:%7E:text=GCC%20stands%20for%20%E2%80%9CGNU%20Compiler,Ada%2C%20D%2C%20and%20Go.)