# How can a language's compiler be written in that language?

Tags: compiler-construction, recursion, bootstrapping

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [implementing a compiler in “itself”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193560/implementing-a-compiler-in-itself)
>   [Bootstrapping a language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13537/bootstrapping-a-language)

How can you write a compiler in the same language as the language you're writing that compiler for? Isn't that sort of recursive?

**Edit**:
This may be deleted, but otherwise... :

**How** to bootstrap:

- [Writing a compiler in its own language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193560/implementing-a-compiler-in-itself)
- [Bootstrapping a language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13537/bootstrapping-a-language)

**Why** to bootstrap:

- [Bootstrapping a compiler: why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493747/bootstrapping-a-compiler-why)

Comment: Various earlier versions and related links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13537/bootstrapping-a-language http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493747/bootstrapping-a-compiler-why http://stackoverflow.com/questions/193560/implementing-a-compiler-in-itself http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173780/programming-language-and-compiler http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035838/what-language-do-they-build-other-languages-with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2740994/what-is-the-language-of-compilersare-they-written-with-different-languages The word you wanted was "bootstrapping".

Comment: I wonder how often people implement compilers for mainstream languages using esoteric ones.

Comment: @Phil Ross - wow, thanks, how'd you find that? wasn't sure how to search :)

Comment: I searched for compiler bootstrapping using the search box in the top right.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Generally the first version of the compiler is written in a different language, and then each subsequent version is written in that language and compiled with the older version. Once you've compiled version `x` with version `x-1`, you can use the newly built version `x` to recompile itself, taking advantage of any new optimizations that version introduces; GCC does its releases that way

Comment: +1 I've built a simple Lisp interpreter in JAVA.

Comment: so... why can't you just use the first version of the compiler? Why would you want a double-level compiler?

Comment: @froadie You mean why not compile every version with version 1? Usually new versions of a compiler generate better machine code than the previous versions, so building with the newest version will make the compiler itself as fast/efficient as possible. Also if the language itself is changing and you want to use those newer features in the compiler's source code, you'll need to build with a more recent version

Comment: @MichaelMrozek that's pretty cool, are you saying that all languages derive from assembly?

Comment: @froadie see this q [bootstrapping-a-compiler-why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493747/bootstrapping-a-compiler-why?lq=1)

Comment: @nawfal - I added a link to that question in my question itself shortly after asking the question several years ago

Comment: @froadie oh yes, I missed it...

Answer (score 17):

It is.  You usually need a bootstrap version of the language either compiled or interpreted from another language.

And to bend your mind a little more, years ago I read the history of a Pascal compiler written as a grad student project.  It written in Pascal and compiled with the system's built-in Pascal compiler.  Eventually, it was good enough to replace the system's built-in Pascal compiler.  Unfortunately, they found a bug in code generation, but the fix for the code generator triggered the bug in the compiler, generating a bad compiler.  To fix it required hand-patching the binaries from the installed compiler to then apply the patch to the source to replace itself.

Comment: I found this question wondering exactly what one would do in this kind of bug situation. Hand-patching had not occurred to me. Funny story. haha

Answer (score 8):

It's only a problem for the very first version ever. Once I have V1.0 of the compiler working I can write V2.0 in my language and use the V1.0 compiler to compile it. Then I can write V3.0 and use V2.0 to compile that, use V3.0 to compile V4.0 and so on.

Answer (score 3):

The first pass of the compiler is normally written in something else until the language is well-formed enough to be able to compile it's own compiler, then you can get into the x is written in x.

Answer (score 2):

At some point, you need a compiler (or interpreter) written in a different language. But it doesn't need to be efficient and can be done in a language that makes parsing and prototyping easy (LISP is popular). Once you have used this to compile the "self-compiler", you can discard it and use the result.

Comment: Not necessarily. The very first "compiler" can also be a human, in which case you do not need a bootstrap compiler in a different language *at all*. This is how the first compilers for most of Niklaus Wirth's languages were written: he basically assigned them to his students :-)

Answer (score 1):

At the very beginning, the real first compiler of that language, was written not in that language of course. Very second could be written in that language. Moreover, given a spec of a language, you can implement a basic core in a bootstrap compiler, and then write the full compliant compiler in that language using the subset understood by the "bootstrap" compiler. Second generation compilers can forget "bootstrap" compiler too.